# Wordpress get_post_meta image width for lazy load

Tags: wordpress, post, get, meta

I'm trying to lazy load a page of images in Wordpress - I've tried the plugins but none of them seem to work(I only want to lazy load image on some pages.)

So I'm now trying to do it with a plugin - http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

This plugin requires the image width and height in the img tag.

```
    <img data-original=“img/example.jpg” src=“img/grey.gif” width=“640” height=“480”>
```

I'm attaching the images from custom fields like

```
    <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'img1', true); ?>">
```

Is it possible get the images width and height from the get_post_meta

I've looked at wp_get_attachment_image_src but I can't see how to use it get_post_meta

======

UPDATE

======

```
    <?php
        $attachments = get_children( 
        array(
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
            'post_status' => 'inherit', 
            'post_type' => 'attachment', 
            'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
            'order' => ASC, 
            'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'
            )
        );

    ?>

    <?php
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

            $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment );

    ?>      
            <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0];?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1];?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2];?>">

    <?php       

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use Wordpress Media Gallery support. You can get all images attached to post with:

```
<?php $attachments = get_children( 
    array('post_parent' => $id, 
        'post_status' => 'inherit', 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
        'order' => ASC, 
        'orderby' => 
        'menu_order ID') ); ?>
```

where `$id` is a current post ID. Then with the ID's of attached images, You can simply use:

```
<?php foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
    (...)
}?>
```

to iterate throught image Id's, and

```
<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size, $icon);>
```

which is described: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src, that allows You not only get url of image, but also its width and height.

The whole code can be wrapped in a shortcode function for ease of use ;).

Comment: Thanks Marcin, this looks a bit beyond my knowledge but I would like to work this out. I have added an update to my post but I'm not getting anything.  - I normally try the Wordpress support but don't normally get a response.

Comment: This is 100% custom template or custom plugin work. You need to know at least some php and wordpress codex. You can find all answers in codex, but without php knowledge about how to connect all together - You will not be able to do anything more.

Comment: I'm comfortable with custom template and some wordpress codex but I was just looking for a few pointers.

Comment: If You only use customfield to insert url to an image (not it's ID) there is probably no way to get back information about image size (which is stored in database when You upload image to Media Gallery).

Comment: Thanks for your help Marcin, I've worked it out with another method. I am using the image URL in the custom field and not the ID.